# Do I have to remove flux residue after soldering?

Tags: plumbing, copper, soldering

I noticed those green stuff on a 2 weeks soldered copper joint, as I have read it comes from excess flux. So I would like to know if I have to always wipe off the joint after soldering? And if so then how should it be done? Just a damp cloth? Is there any flux without acid? Or maybe its not from flux at all? There are no leaks at or around the joint.

Comment: Joints should be wiped off after sweating. I would use paper towels saturated with water first, then with damp rag or damp paper towels. What does the label on the flux container state? What does the label on the roll of solder state?

Comment: I am assuming your talking on soldering copper pipe, which is done with an acid brush-on paste and using non-flux core solder, compared to soldering wire which is a non-acid flux core based solder.  It is the acid that is making the cooper oxidize and turn green and as stated needs washed.  I like to use a pail of water with a couple spoons of A&H baking soda added to neutralize the acid when I wipe it down.

Comment: If this is water pipe acid flux would not be recommended. Most of the acid core solder I have is not for potable water because it contains lead and acid. I usually wipe joints with a water saturated rag after soldering. With the more aggressive flux types if not removed they will etch the copper over time making a weak point so wiping them off is a good idea.

Comment: Rosin-core electrical solder does not cause corrosion, but as mentioned above, should not be used on potable water.

Comment: So is there any flux for water pipe without flux?

Comment: http://www.rectorseal.com/nokorode-regular-paste-flux/ but it's still a best practice to wipe the joint clean with a damp rag while still quite warm (but not while the solder is still liquid.) You can also use a rag and a bucket of hot water later.